# Disable sd card wear leveling

Tags: c++, arduino, device-driver

I've been trying to write software that erases completely my sd card but i read that sd cards keep data blocks for replace dameged data blocks.

I try for some time to make my sd card to disable the wear leveling option but i coludn't find info about this.

I hope you could help me,
BK.

Comment: The short answer is most likely to be "You cannot" (at least not reliably).

Answer (score 1):

Most SD cards don't expose any interface to disable this wear leveling. Even if some do, it's a proprietary interface, and I've heard of no brand that actually can do this.

You thus cannot disable wear leveling. However overwriting, you will not be able to retrieve the old data blocks by software means.

So simply overwriting (or using the TRIM command, if available) will be good enough, since you probably won't have NSA as your enemy.